# C++ how do i show ledstatus as on or off in the Client?

Tags: c++, arduino

The code is Arduino C++ how do I show ledstatus as "on" or "off" in the HTTP Client?
The Led/status in the if statement does not like Ledstatus = off; or Ledstatus = on; why? but works if I substitute with numbers what am I doing wrong?

please help?

```
/*
  Web Server

 A simple web server that shows the value of the analog input pins.
 using an Arduino Wiznet Ethernet shield.

 Circuit:
 * Ethernet shield attached to pins 10, 11, 12, 13
 * Analog inputs attached to pins A0 through A5 (optional)

 created 18 Dec 2009
 by David A. Mellis
 modified 9 Apr 2012
 by Tom Igoe

 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <Wire.h>

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
};
IPAddress ip(10,0, 0, 210);
char linebuffer[20];
int linenumber = 0;

boolean IsLed = false;

// (Spa Variables):
int LedOn;
int Ledstatus;






// Initialize the Ethernet server library
// with the IP address and port you want to use
// (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetServer server(80);


void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  // Set Digital Pin 12 to output:
  pinMode(12,OUTPUT);

  // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  digitalWrite (12,LOW);
}


void loop() {
  // listen for incoming clients
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    Serial.println("new client");

    // an http request ends with a blank line
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;

    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();

        Serial.write(c);
        // if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
        // character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
        // so you can send a reply
        if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank){
          // send a standard http response header
          parseRequest();
          //sendHTTPResponse(client);
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println("Connection: close");  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
          client.println("Refresh: 5");  // refresh the page automatically every 5 sec
          client.println();
          client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
          client.println("<html>");
          client.println("OK ");
          client.print(IsLed);
          client.print(Ledstatus);



          char linebuffer[20]; //Clear the line buffer
          linenumber = 0;

          break;

        }
        if (c == '\n'){
          // you're starting a new line
          currentLineIsBlank = true;
        }else if (c != '\r') {
          if(linenumber <20){ //If there is room in the buffer
            linebuffer[linenumber] = c; //Add char to the buffer
            linenumber++; //Increment the counter
         }
        // you've gotten a character on the current line
          currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(10);
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("client disconnected");
  }
}

void parseRequest(){
  if(linebuffer[5] == 'O' && linebuffer[6] == 'N'){ //if the request was for ON 
  //Turn on the LED
  IsLed = true;
  digitalWrite (12,LOW);
  Serial.println("isLed ON");
  Ledstatus= on;

  }else{(linebuffer[5] == 'O' && linebuffer [6] == 'F' && linebuffer [7] == 'F'); //if the request was for OFF
  //Turn OFF the LED
  IsLed = false;
  digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
  Serial.println("isLed OFF");
  Serial.println();
  Ledstatus = off;
  }
} 

​
```

Comment: What is `off` and `on`?  I can't find them defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: Sorry but I can't see the Position in the code what is not working. Can you mark it?

Comment: Ledstatus = off; and Ledstatus= on; in the last If and else statement shows a error when I complie it. All I want is to  get the client to show led on or off on the http browser. the compile error I get is Ethernet_Claycode_test2.ino:134:14: error: 'on' was not declared in this scope
Ethernet_Claycode_test2.ino:142:15: error: 'off' was not declared in this scope

Comment: OK10 or OKOO is all I get in the web browser HTTP client. I want it to say OK ON or OK OFF

Comment: I think you are Messing up some things here. Because you never fill `linebuffer`with anything. Also with the line `char linebuffer[20]; //Clear the line buffer`you are not Clearing the line but declaring a new variable.

Comment: Mate I don't want to touch the line buffer do I as it works? , I just want the HTTP browser to show OK ON or OK OFF when I browser request 10.0.0.210/on and 10.0.0.210/off. I tried to create the "Led status" variable to show "on" and "off" depending on the if statement but text is not working when I say add ledstatus =on or ledstatus =off. Can I make a variable text? as Led status =5 and Ledstatus = 6 works if I use numbers? in the parseRequest(); function

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally got you, because your code is somehow confusing! As you wrote in the comment you get a `OK10` or `OKOO` because you are printing this in your code:

```
...
client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
client.println("Connection: close");  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
client.println("Refresh: 5");  // refresh the page automatically every 5 sec
client.println();
client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
client.println("<html>");
client.println("OK ");   //Prints OK of course
client.print(IsLed);     //Prints an int!!
client.print(Ledstatus); //Also prints an int!!
...
```

You Need to Change it to something like this:

```
...
client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
client.println("Connection: close");  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
client.println("Refresh: 5");  // refresh the page automatically every 5 sec
client.println();
client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
client.println("<html>");
client.print("OK ");   //Prints OK of course
if(Ledstatus == on)
    client.println("ON");
else
    client.println("OFF");
...
```

Also what I mentioned in the comments, you don't read line buffer from the Client but you are parsing it. It will be empty! I don't know about the API but there must be a function similar to

```
client.read(linubuffer, 20);
```